# What is the difference between no match (red) and no match (blue) in dialogflow analytic?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

We already created a chat bot with dialogflow. Now, we want to test it and need some measurement or analytic data to make sure the bot is ready for public. One of the ways we use "Analytic" feature from dialogflow. but, there not any specific/detail contains about it in their Docs. then, we confuse what is the difference of this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLPKu.png)

Comment: I think the difference is that for the red one the user quit the skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some contact with the DF team and the same request. Here is the answere of DF:

> I spoke to my engineers for the clarification. The blue "No Match"
>   nodes are mislabeled and our engineers started working on this fix.
>   The blue group represents all the other intents that didn't have a
>   large enough volume to show up as their own node and the red nodes
>   would be fallback intents. So, the blue and red represents
>   "Handled"/"Not Handled"

I hope this is helpful for you